# Drop down menu in python form

Tags: forms, web2py

I have a web2py application and want to create a form where I am able to make a drop down menu, which has several options to choose, which dont come from a database. 1st Is this even possible with web2py and if yes, how would I do that and read out it's value?

Comment: You can create a standard HTML form, and the submitted variables will be in `request.vars`. Also, have you read the [forms documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#FORM)?